# Calculating a Run-Time of a loop

Tags: algorithm, for-loop, time, runtime, time-complexity

I'm trying to prove that the following algorithm runs in O(n^2) time.

I'm given the Code:
Which is mostly psedocode

```
function generalFunction(value)
  for(i=1 to value.length-1)// value is an array, and this runs `n-1 Times`
     for(j=1 to value.length-i // This runs `n-1(n-1)` times?
       if value[j-1] > value[j] //This runs n^2 times?
         swap A[j+1] and value[j] //How would would this run?
```

For the first line, I calculated that it runs `n-1` times. Because the loop goes n times, but since we are subtracting a 1 from the length of the arbritray array, it would be `n-1` times (I believe).

The Same can be said for the second line, except we have to multiply it by the original for loop.

However, I'm not sure about the last two lines, would the third one run in n^2 times? I only wrote n^2 because of the two nested loops. I'm not sure how to go about approaching the last line either, any input would be much appreciated.

Comment: in terms of Big O the last two lines run in constant time i.e. O(1) operations. they can be ignored. and n^2 is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this will run in n^2 - as per your comments. Note that the execution of the inner if statement (swap) is irrelevant to the fact that double loop run n^2 times. Also, the minus one part (n-1) still makes it n^2, since you are basically looking for an upper bound ~approximation~ and n^2 is the tightest such bound. Basically (n-1)(n-1) = n^2 - 2n +1 is dominated by n^2 term.

For definition and workable example similar to this see [Wikipedi - example section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation)

P.S. Bug O is about the -worst- case scenario. So in the worst case, the if statement will always be true, hence swap will hit each loop cycle. meaning if you put a break point, it will get hit (n-1)*(n-1) times. Expanding that means n^2 - 2n + 1 times.

Comment: So I could write something like "Since n^2 -2n+1 is 0(n^2), the algorithm is 0(n^2)?

Comment: Also Shouldn’t it be n^2-2n+1+n^2 = 2n^2-2n+1 which is O(n^2)

Comment: See the edit and link to wikipedia example doing what you are. Not sure where you getting the second n^2 from but either way, the coefficient is not relevant. Only the n^2 is. Again refer to discussion the example of the wiki link.

Comment: still kinda confused, I was told to sum up all the values (n-1)(n-1) + the rest. Then write "since this is..... big o of... etc". I'm getting the coefficent when adding n^2 + n^2 (the second n^2 from the 3rd line of code).